# Why does my custom event throw an exception?

Tags: c#, events

I'm writing a program that logs user idle time, however when I attempt to run the program it throws a Stack Overflow Exception.

These are my custom events

```
public void OnInactive(EventArgs e)
{
    this.OnInactive(new EventArgs());
    do
    {
        var idle2 = GetIdleTime();
        GetIdleTime();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(idle2);
    }
    while (timer.Interval > 5000);
}

public void OnActive(EventArgs e)
{
    this.OnActive(new EventArgs());
    if (timer.Interval < 5000)
    {
        var idle3 = GetIdleTime();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(idle3);
    }
}
```

I've breakpointed the code to try and locate the source of the issue, which appears to lie within `this.OnInactive(new EventArgs());`, However I'm pretty stumped on how to resolve this issue as I'm a beginner to Custom Events and haven't been coding in C# for long.

Any and all help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance =]

Comment: First of all remove all the breakpoints and work with log file. you can put following lines to add log file File.AppendAllText(path, "MessageValueOrVariableValue")

Comment: That's a little vague, all I'm trying to do is get this event to fire

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your handler method is calling itself immediately on entry:

```
this.OnInactive(new EventArgs());
```

this leads to a sequence of calls:

OnInactive -> OnInactive -> OnInactive -> ... ->

which will continue until you run out of stack space and the `StackOverflowException` is thrown by the runtime.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve with the recursive call, but you should be able to just remove it.

You have the same issue in your `OnActive` handler.

EDIT: In response to the comments, it seems you're trying to raise the event itself at the beginning of your method. Assuming your event declaration looks like:

```
public event EventHandler InActive;
```

then you can raise it with:

```
EventHandler inactiveEvent = this.InActive;
if(inactiveEvent != null)
{
    inactiveEvent(this, e);
}
```

and similarly for your `Active` event.

Comment: Thanks for the Super-Fast answer Lee, However I've already tried this solution and the event doesn't appear to be firing at all when I comment those lines of code out and from what I understand through researching on the web I need this call for the event to fire

Comment: Maybe he meant `base.onInactive()`

Comment: @ReeceCottam - The handler must be called once, otherwise you would never get the stack overflow. How are you registering the event handle? Your `OnInactive` and `OnActive` handlers do not have the expected signature for event handlers.

Comment: Just to clarify, my reasoning for using a recursive call in this way is because I assumed you needed it in order for the event to fire, which is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: these aren't event handlers, these are the methods that are going to be called in order to raise the active and inactive events

Comment: @ReeceCottam - I've updated the answer to show how to raise the event itself.

Comment: Brilliant! thanks very much =] still nothing showing up in the console window but the event is definitely firing now

Answer (score 0):

I gues you are trying to call the base method, but in fact you are now calling `OnInactive` when hitting `OnInactive`. This behaviour is recursive and will finaly stop due `StackOverflow exception`.

You can call the base function with `base.<function name>`.
For example:

```
class SpecialDerived : Base
{
    public override void Say()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called from Special Derived.");
        base.Say();
    }
}
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: No, I'm trying to get this event to fire, which it doesn't appear to be doing at the moment

Answer (score 0):

> these aren't event handlers, these are the methods that are going to
>   be called in order to raise the active and inactive events – Reece
>   Cottam

You need to actually call the event.

```
public class ReecesWatcher
{
    public event EventHandler ActiveEvent;
    public event EventHandler InactiveEvent;


    protected virtual void OnInactive(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Fire the event using the () syntax. Fire it through
        // a test variable so that we can reliabilty test for null, 
        // if there are no subscribers.
        EventHandler inactiveEventTest = InactiveEvent;
        if (inactiveEventTest != null)
        {
            inactiveEventTest(this, new EventArgs());
        }

        do
        {
            var idle2 = GetIdleTime();
            GetIdleTime();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(idle2);
        }
        while (timer.Interval > 5000);
    }

    protected virtual void OnActive(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Fire the event using the () syntax. Fire it through
        // a test variable so that we can reliabilty test for null, 
        // if there are no subscribers.
        EventHandler activeEventTest = ActiveEvent;
        if (activeEventTest != null)
        {
            activeEventTest(this, new EventArgs());
        }

        if (timer.Interval < 5000)
        {
            var idle3 = GetIdleTime();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(idle3);
        }
    }

    // ... the rest of your class, where you call OnActive and OnInactive to 
    // cause the events to be fired.
}
```

I recommend not making your OnActive and OnInactive methods public, otherwise you're exposing too much of the implementation to the rest of your program. If you expect the class to be inherited from, then make them protected, otherwise I usually make them entirely private, since they're basically wrapper functions called by the rest of the class.

Comment: Important edit! I left out the 'virtual' keyword for the protected methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a bit more understanding about events. Let me explain the same through a sample code.

```
Class A{
   public event  OnInactive;
   public event  OnActive;
}
```

when any changes occur in classA you want to update things in ClassB. So you will implement events of class A in ClassB.

[this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5043/Step-by-Step-Event-handling-in-C) link will describe you the same in detail.

**My understanding says that there is no use of events when you are triggering it from the same class and listening in the same class.**